# No WiFi internet on Ubuntu under VirtualBox

Tags: wireless, networking, virtualbox, internet

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 under VirtualBox 4.3.20 on a Windows 8.1 host. I can't get any internet access over WiFi (and I can't get an Ethernet connection anywhere near the computer). All of the help I can find when I Google this problem either a) tells me to change Windows 7 settings that I can't find in Windows 8.1, or b) tells me to `sudo apt-get install` something, which doesn't work because I have no internet connection.

Can somebody tell me in easy steps (I don't really know Linux, and I certainly don't know networking) how to get the internet connection working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What Virtualbox actually does is share the internet connection of your host (Windows 8.1), with your guest (Ubuntu 14.04). Your guest should be able to detect the wireless internet connection of your host as ethernet connection.

You can check http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html for more information about how to set this up.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I'm afraid you've overestimated my understanding of networking. The article you linked is completely incomprehensible to me.

Comment: everything the virtual machine sees is just that - virtual. There's no physical components. Virtualbox tricks the operating system into thinking it's connected to physical hardware, so your virtual machine only sees the illusion of a wired connection, which is actually just passing information through to your computer's normal connection.